# Prevent applications from automatically starting

Tags: windows, windows-xp, boot

In Windows, there are generally 2 ways a program automatically launches

1. Start Up folder
2. A Registry entry (in HKLM,HKCU/Software/Microsoft/Windows/CurrentVersion/Run

Is there a way to **prevent** applications from being added for automatic startup?

Note: I am not talking about manually deleting the registry keys/startup shortcuts or using the `msconfig` utility.

For example, I put deny privileges for all users to read/access/write to the HKLM registry key, which helped some. I do not want to to do that to HKCU since there are legitimate things in there I want started.

So, I am looking for a method to prevent anything (legitimate applications, virues, malware, etc) from adding themselves as an entry, but allow the valid ones already entered to be read.

Comment: Why cant you just give users read rights but not full control?

Comment: The registry doesn't have those types of permissions. There is no distinction between read and write/modify. At least on Windows XP.

Comment: Ah, it exists on windows 7. According to [this](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/regedit_permit_key.mspx?mfr=true) it is in windows XP professional at least...

Comment: On the version I have, I cannot Deny Write without Denying Read as well. Perhaps I need to finish updating it first.

Comment: Are there special permissions that you can set?

Answer (score 0):

### [WhatInStartup](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/what_run_in_startup.html)

Supports a special "Permanent Disabling" feature - If a program that you previously disabled added itself again to the startup list of Windows, WhatInStartup will automatically detect the change and disable it again.

[image]